# SQL Select row from table with some minimum value from another table

Tags: sql

I suppose this is not so hard but I can not get it.

For example I have table `T1`:

```
ID    
-----
1000
1001
```

And I have table `T2`:

```
ID      GROUP  DATE
--------------------------
1000    ADSL   2.2.2012
1000    null   3.2.2012
1000    NOC    4.2.2012
1001    NOC    5.2.2012
1001    null   6.2.2012
1001    TV    7.2.2012
```

I want to select from `T1` only the row that has as `GROUP` value `NOC` from `T2` but only if `NOC` group is for the minimum `DATE` value in `T2`.

So my result in this case would be only `1001` because for its minimum `DATE` 5.2.2012 Group is `NOC`!

I do not want any joins and I can not use default values for IDs (`where id=1000 or id=1001`) because this is just example of some big table.

Important also is that I can not use `t1.id = t2.id` because in some application where I am using this I can not write the whole SQL expression but only partial. I can only use id.

I tried something like:

```
select id 
from t1 
where
   id in (select id from t2 
          where group = 'NOC' 
          and date in (select min(date) from t2 
                       where id in (select id from t1) 
                      )
         )
```

But this does not work.

I know it seems little confusing but I really can't use `where t1.id = t2.id`

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error because `group` is a reserved word?

Comment: no I am not (real name of the field is PEOPLEGROUP) so it's not problem

Comment: I am getting the output but my result is not correct for that big table

Comment: Why 1001? The minimum date with 'NOC' is 4.2.2012 and 1000 is in T1?

Comment: It would be useful to understand all of the restrictions you're working under, and which part(s) of the query you're allowed to specify, and which not. Is this part of some product? If so, is there any online documentation for it?

Comment: I don't think this is doable without a join *somewhere*. Is avoiding a join a hard requirement (you said "I do not want any joins" but that could be you stating a preference)? I can't see a way to avoid needing to correlate two columns at least once - which RDBMS are you working against?

Comment: Stefan minimum date for 1000 is 2.2 and for that record group is ADSL not NOC! For 1001 minimum date is 5.2 and group is NOC so it fulfills condition.

Comment: Damien I am using DB2. I have restriction as I can start writing my query only after this part    select id 
from t1 
where
So I can not change this first part of the query it must start like this and this is invisible for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T2.ID` is a foreign key referencing `T1.ID`, you don't really need the `T1` table, because all the IDs could be obtained from `T2` only:

```
SELECT o.ID
FROM T2 AS o
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT MIN(i.DATE)
  FROM T2 AS i
  WHERE i.ID = o.ID
  HAVING MIN(i.DATE) = o.DATE
)
WHERE o."GROUP" = 'NOC'
```

But if you insist on involving `T1`, you just need to modify the above like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT o.ID
  FROM T2 AS o
  WHERE o."GROUP" = 'NOC'
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT MIN(i.DATE)
      FROM T2 AS i
      WHERE i.ID = o.ID
      HAVING MIN(i.DATE) = o.DATE
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this in multiple steps?

First of all, to get the minimum date per id, you would need:

```
select id, peoplegroup, min(date)
from t2
group by id
```

That will give you

```
1000    ADSL   2.2.2012
1001    NOC    5.2.2012
```

Call this table t3.

Then do

```
select id
from t3
where id in (
  select id from t1
)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, looks like I misunderstood the question.  I was looking for the overall minimum date.  I have changed the answer.

Comment: We don't (yet) know which product the OP is using, but most of them will reject that first query because `peoplegroup` is not in the `GROUP BY` nor in an aggregate. (MySQL is the only product I'm aware of that will allow it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id from t1 where id in
 (select id from t2 where group = 'NOC' and date =
   (select min(date) from t2 where id = t1.id))
```

Comment: Gives 1000, not 1001. Also, when adding code, highlight it and hit the `{}` button, so that we get nice code formatting/highlighting.